# Windows 10 BSOD System_Service_Error when running VM under VMware Workstation 15 Player

Tags: windows-10, bsod, vmware-player, avast

I used to have my Ubuntu VM run fine inside VMware Workstation 15 Player under Windows 10.

Today after a power outage, I suddenly noticed that each time I start the VM inside the player, I get BSOD in the host with error System_Service_Exception in Win 10. I found in the internet that the antivirus (Avast or AVG) can cause this problem. My configuration is problem between Avast 19.5.2378 (build 19.5.4444.507) and VMware Workstations 15 Player. I disabled Avast for an hour and things worked out fine. Once the one hour passed, I got the BSOD again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround which succeeded for several hours running the VM while Avast is enabled, which is simply to add an exception for the File Shield in Avast for the folder that has the VM. That is it. This prevents Avast from scanning and probably interfering with the VM files on the disk causing the crash.

I am sharing this workaround to help others with the same problem.